# Warning:Instantiation depth... This might indicate a recursive instantiation

Tags: verilog

I want to implement 4to1 mux with 2to1 mux. But, I can't simulate 4to1 mux testbench.

I searched the problems already in other sources, but I can't find the problem.

```
module mux2to1(I0,I1,A,Z);
    input I0,I1,A;
    output Z;

    assign Z = (~A & I0) | (A & I1);
endmodule
```

```
module mux4to1(I0,I1,I2,I3,A,B,Z,R3,R4);
    input I0,I1,I2,I3,A,B;
    output Z,R3,R4;
    
    mux2to1 mux2 (I0,I1,B,R3);
    mux2to1 mux3 (I2,I3,B,R4);
    mux2to1 mux4 (R3,R4,A,Z);

endmodule
```

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
module mux4to1_tb();
    reg I0,I1,I2,I3,A,B,R3,R4;
    wire Z;
    
    mux4to1 mux5 (I0,I1,I2,I3,A,B,Z,R3,R4);

    initial begin
        A=0; B=0; I0=1; I1=0; I2=0; I3=0; #1;
        A=0; B=0; I0=0; I1=0; I2=0; I3=0; #1;
    
        A=0; B=1; I0=0; I1=1; I2=0; I3=0; #1;
        A=0; B=1; I0=0; I1=0; I2=0; I3=0; #1;

        A=1; B=0; I0=0; I1=0; I2=1; I3=0; #1;
        A=1; B=0; I0=0; I1=0; I2=0; I3=0; #1;

        A=1; B=1; I0=0; I1=0; I2=0; I3=1; #1;
        A=1; B=1; I0=0; I1=0; I2=0; I3=0;
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I compile your code on another simulator, I get this helpful compile error message:

```
    mux4to1 mux5 (I0,I1,I2,I3,A,B,Z,R3,R4);
                                     |
xmelab: *E,RANOTL : A reg is not a legal lvalue in this context [6.1.2(IEEE)].
```

When connecting signals to module outputs, you should declare them as `wire`, not `reg`.  In your testbench, change:

```
reg I0,I1,I2,I3,A,B,R3,R4;
wire Z;
```

to:

```
reg I0,I1,I2,I3,A,B;
wire Z,R3,R4;
```

This clears up the errors for me, and the simulations runs for me without warnings.  You can also try to run your code on different simulators on edaplayground.  Sometimes you get more helpful messages.